# Does c++ std's inf behave exactly as common-sensical infinity

Tags: c++, overflow, std, infinity

I was implementing a reasonably complicated numerical algorithm. 
It contains some exponentials, among which I discovered, upon printing the intermediate result, that there were some overflows of double. 
However, the terminal prints `inf` (not `Inf` or `NaN`), and it seems that it is not a double, not even the minimum or maximum expressible double. 
But it seems `inf` behaves as if it were the extended real number system (the perspective that positive and negative infinity be regarded as a true number, rather than an abbreviation of statement involving limits).

I have conducted a test: (g++ version: "Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)")

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <cmath> // exp, log
#include <limits> // data ranges

int main(void)
{
   const double dMin =std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
   const double dMax =std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
   double p1 =std::exp(710);
   double p2 =std::exp(750);
   double p3 =std::exp(800);
   double p4 =-std::log(0.0);
   std::cout << "p1 :=std::exp(710) =" << p1 << '\n';
   std::cout << "p2 :=std::exp(750) =" << p2 << '\n';
   std::cout << "p3 :=std::exp(800) =" << p3 << '\n';
   std::cout << "p4 :=-std::log(0.0) =" << p4 << '\n';
   std::cout << "does p1==dMax? " << ( (p1==dMax) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does p1==-dMin? " << ( (p1==-dMin) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does p1==p2? " << ( (p1==p2) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does p2==p3? " << ( (p2==p3) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does p3==p4? " << ( (p3==p4) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does 3*p1==p2/2+1? " << ( (3*p1==p2/2+1) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does (-p1)*(-p2)==p3*p3*p3? " << ( ((-p1)*(-p2)==p3*p3*p3) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
   std::cout << "does std::log(p2)==std::exp(p3)? " << ( (std::log(p2)==std::exp(p3)) ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
p1 :=std::exp(710) =inf
p2 :=std::exp(750) =inf
p3 :=std::exp(800) =inf
p4 :=-std::log(0.0) =inf
does p1==dMax? no
does p1==-dMin? no
does p1==p2? yes
does p2==p3? yes
does p3==p4? yes
does 3*p1==p2/2+1? yes
does (-p1)*(-p2)==p3*p3*p3? yes
does std::log(p2)==std::exp(p3)? yes
```

It seems that `inf` does resemble our concept of infinity, but not equal to std's max and min.

Is it safe, then, to assume that `inf` works in the same manner as common-sensical infinity? 
May I rely on operations in the intermediate steps of my algorithm which involves `inf`, taking it to be true infinity, and only deal with its results in the end? 
Or if not, should I catch it? But how can I, since it is not the maximum or minimum double?

Comment: "common-sensical infinity", i'm finding it hard to contain my laughter right now :D

Comment: well I am not native English user QQ

Comment: ^^ it's not the English, just the assertion that there exists a sensical infinity.

Comment: Okay, as I said, the extended real line. (I know what it is normally defined by x->\infty) (and I see you are well meant XD )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by the other answers, the behavior of floating point numbers is not well-defined by the standard, however it is pretty well defined by [IEC-559/IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), and most implementation use this. The first thing to do would be to check if your implementation effectively uses it:

```
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559, "Stupid implementation!");
```

Once you passed that assertion, things get a lot easier! First, you can use the following utility function to obtain a *true* infinity (you do not need `is_iec559` to be true for this to work actually... ):

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
```

Better, IEEE-754 has very well-defined rules for the behavior of infinity: 
http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html#operations<sup>1</sup>, e.g. `-inf * -inf = +inf`, `+inf + +inf = +Inf`, and so on. Standard mathematical functions have also well-defined behavior with infinity, so you can rely on them too.

So if your implementation follows the IEEE standard, **yes** you can rely on intermediate operations on infinity and only check the final results.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is not an official resource but as far as I know, it is correct.</sub>

Comment: Upvoted for karma (and the fact that this answer is really rather good) - I've nicked one of your comments you've made and put it in my answer.

Comment: Yes, mine has `is_iec559` true. Good news. (Excuse me that only by now I have time to check this.)

Answer (score 3):

Restricting this answer to IEEE754 floating point, +Inf arises from a computation like `1.0 / 0.0`, and -Inf arises from something like `-1.0 / 0.0`.

Another type, `NaN` (not a number) arises from `0.0 / 0.0`.

Two floating point variables set to `+Inf` will compare `true` with each other, ditto `-Inf`. They represent different quantities to `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`. `+Inf` is larger than all values except itself and `NaN`.

Note that two floating point variables set to `NaN` will **not** compare `true` with each other, or with anything else for that matter.

(For what it's worth, `std::log(0.0)` *must* return `-Inf`, rather than `NaN`). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log

Comment: `std::log(0.0)` should probably return `-Inf` ;)

Comment: I could swear that it must return +Inf: will dig out the standard later. Mathematically log(0) is one of the worst poles you can encounter.

Comment: I checked, it is really `inf`. Why is it the worst pole? Is it because log(0) cannot be Laurent-expanded? (I suppose not, but don't know how to show.) --- a digression anyway, pardon.

Comment: @Aminopterin How did you check? I don't have access to the IEEE754 standard, but [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) says that it should return `-inf`, your experiment show that it returns `-inf`, and my own tests show that it returns `-inf` - I don't see why it would return `+inf`.

Comment: @Holt: Oops. Learn something new every day.

Comment: No, no, I said `-std::log(0.0)` is `inf`, with a minus sign. I was wondering, in the previous comment of mine, that whether `Inf` is different with `inf`.

Comment: As I saw, `std::log(0.0)` equals to `-inf` always; sorry if misunderstood.

Comment: @Aminopterin Not really always, but most of the times ;) The implementation has to follow the IEEE standard for that. There are others interesting rules such that `exp(-inf) = 0`, or `atan(+inf) = +pi/2`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does *c++ std's inf* ...

The C++ standard doesn't specify any requirements for how infinity behaves - or that infinity can be represented by floating point numbers.

If your system uses floating point numbers that conform to a particular floating point standard, then that standard might specify the behaviour of infinities.

> It seems that inf does resemble our concept of infinity, but not equal to std's max and min.

Indeed. `numeric_limits::max()` is defined to return the maximum **finite** value.

> how [to *catch* infinity], since it is not the maximum or minimum double?

If by *catch* you mean that you wish to check whether a value is infinity, you can compare to `numeric_limits::infinity()`, or if you have C++11, then `std::isinf()` (which checks for both positive and negative infinity).